# How to add included Pug files to Vite module graph

Tags: vue.js, pug, vite

I wrote a Rollup plugin to import Pug as an HTML string:

```
// Rollup plugin imported to Vite config

import { render } from 'pug';

export default function pug() {
  return {
    name: 'rollup-plugin-pug-html',

    transform(src, id) {
      if (id.endsWith('.pug')) {
        const html = render(src, { filename: id });
        const code = `export default ${JSON.stringify(html)};`;

        return { code };
      }
    },
  };
}
```

I'm using it in Vite to create templates for Vue components, as in this reduced example:

```
// ProofOfConceptSFC.vue

<script>
import { compile } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';
import template from './template.pug';

export default {
  render: compile(template)
};
</script>
```

The HMR is working great when I edit `template.pug`. The new template appears and the latest reactive values persist.

My problem is that `template.pug` may depend on other Pug files with `include`:

```
//- template.pug

include ./header.pug
p Hello {{ name }}
include ./footer.pug
```

The Vite server doesn't know about those files, and nothing happens if I touch them. Ideally I could invalidate `template.pug` when any Pug file is changed.

I'm guessing I want my plugin to update the ViteDevServer's `server.moduleGraph`. Is there a supported way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huge thanks to the friendly [Vite chat on Discord](https://chat.vitejs.dev/) for setting me in the right direction.

The two keys I was missing:

1. Use Pug `compile` to create a `render` method that has `render.dependencies`, [as done by Parcel](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/blob/v2/packages/transformers/pug/src/PugTransformer.js#L28-L38)
2. Use virtual import statements to attach the dependencies to the transform hook result, [as done by vite-plugin-svelte](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/packages/vite-plugin-svelte/src/utils/compile.ts#L58).

Here is the working plugin:

```
import { compile } from 'pug';

export default function pluginPug() {
  return {
    name: 'vite-plugin-pug',

    transform(src, id) {
      if (id.endsWith('.pug')) {
        const render = compile(src, { filename: id });
        const html = render();
        let code = '';

        for (let dep of render.dependencies) {
          code += `import ${JSON.stringify(dep)};\n`;
        }

        code += `export default ${JSON.stringify(html)};`;

        return { code };
      }
    },
  };
}
```